# Access 2013 Web App linked to client-side Access 2007 database

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2013

I have developed a access 2007 database that is hosted on the clients server.  They input data 24/7 in house, and enjoy the fast speed of the local connection.  However, they are now wanting to view this data on a mobile device.  I would like to be able to create a new Access 2013 web app, and have my current access 2007 database transfer data to a hosted server somewhere, where the access 2013 web app will run from.  There won't be any need to add/edit/delete data from mobile, just view, so that saves me a lot of trouble with having to convert all my vba.  I just have no idea how to go about this, or if it is possible.  If I use a hosted sharepoint server, can I add my web app there, and be able to transfer data to the server to view?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Access 2013 web uses SQL Azure, and starting with Access 2010  is when support for Azure was introduced. I not at all sure you can thus use Access 2007 to connect to a 2013 web database (you should be able to use 2010 or 2013).

I think in this case you might consider just building a simple asp.net web site and then have Access 2007 send some data to that site (assuming the site allows external ODBC connections – these are becoming harder to find these days).

As I alternative I suppose you could upgrade to Access 2013, and for existing desktops deploy the FREE 2013 runtime. This should in theory allow you to keep your existing application, and also connect to the 2013 web application you publish. You have to sort up the users permissions here.

So while the Access client(desktop edition) can link to published Access web applications, I don't believe that Access 2007 can be used since it does not have support built in for using SQL Azure like 2010 and 2013 does.

Comment: So, lets say I convert my access 2007 desktop app to a 2013 desktop app.  Would I store the back end on a web server, and link the desktop to it, or would I just set up some ftp to transfer the locally stored back-end to the web server so that the 2013 web app could have semi-current data.  I can't quite figure out how to have the data stored on the local server and send that same data to a web location.

Comment: In all cases simply taking about using linked tables to SharePoint. The suggesting is thus based on using Access 2010 or later which has SIGNIFICAT performance enhancements over 2007. Access 2010/2013 gives you a automatic local cache of data and results in great performance. This setup means do don't use ftp and you don’t change anything. The local off line mode is built in and requires NO changes. Simply move the tables to SharePoint and link to them from your front ends. At that point you have a local off line application that syncs when on-line.